# webpack server live reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, livereload, webpacker

I'm building a `react-rails` app with `rails 5.2`.

[`react-rails-hot-loader`](https://github.com/rmosolgo/react-rails-hot-loader) is not compatible with `rails 5.2`, the live reloding would work with [`react_on_rails`](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails) and I am trying to understand how to configure `webpacker` to live-reload

I had a read at the [following issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/842)

I run `./bin/webpack-dev-server --inline=false` and my `rails s` in a separate terminal instance, but I can not display the site on webpacker `localhost:3035/movies`. The output in the browser is `Cannot GET /movies`

I just created the [repository](https://github.com/fabriziobertoglio1987/moviesdb), do not know `webpacker` and would really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`webpacker 3.3.5`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#development) supports hot reloading

running `./bin/webpack-dev-server`  and `rails s` in a different terminal allows you to use `hot reloading features`

My understanding is that `webpacker` development server will provide the `js`, `css` and `image` assets to the rails server.

The application is available at `localhost:3000` (from the `rails server`) for development with hot reloading. I started the `webpacker` dev server before my `rails s`

Some more article explains more in details how to configure the `webpacker server`

https://medium.com/statuscode/introducing-webpacker-7136d66cddfb
https://medium.com/rubyinside/hot-module-reloading-with-webpacker-b663643a60b1https://github.com/justisb/react_on_rails/blob/master/docs/additional-reading/hot-reloading-rails-development.md
https://learnetto.com/tutorials/hot-module-replacement